# SQL - Left join with the same table, problem when matching left and right table using ON statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to SQL. consider the following table(table1)

```
s_id    v_id
1       1
2       1
2       2
2       3
2       5
2       6
2       7
3       1
3       2
3       6
3       7
3       8
4       1
and so on
```

Here please consider s_id 2 and 3 only for now. I want the records of s_id=2 which is not available in s_id=3( v_id 3 and 5 ). Don't bother about the new ids in s_id=3 (v_id 8)

Output that I need

```
s_id    v_id
2       3
2       5
```

I tried the following query, but it is returning the reverse of what I need.

```
SELECT a.* 
  from table1 a 
  LEFT 
  JOIN table1 b 
    ON a.v_id = b.v_id 
 WHERE a.s_id = 2 
   AND b.s_id = 3
```

Here I know the condition in ON statement is wrong.
It should be like this

```
a.v_id is not in b.v_id
```

Here I don't want to have a sub query.
Join or simple query is welcomed.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: Using Postgresql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6H4ubXubMgJuoadXuxHbv4/0

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1
WHERE s_id = 2
  AND v_id NOT IN (
      SELECT v_id 
      FROM t1
      WHERE s_id = 3
      )
```

Or you can transform your `JOIN` query to:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vCVDCV9sCu7F8QoFiU5in9/1

```
SELECT a.* from table1 a 
LEFT JOIN table1 b 
ON a.v_id = b.v_id
   AND b.s_id=3
WHERE a.s_id=2 
   AND b.v_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Another aggregation query, maybe less likely to break any brains:

```
SELECT max(s_id) AS s_id, v_id
FROM   tbl
WHERE  s_id in (2, 3)
GROUP  BY v_id
HAVING max(s_id) = 2;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=29a04d2231504a1f01de5ba30a0bd908)*

(Also, repeating `max(s_id)` should be a bit cheaper.)

Lists all `v_id` for which `s_id = 2` is found (1 or more times), but not the greater `s_id = 3`.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting alternative approach uses aggregation:

```
select max(s_id) as s_id, v_id
from t
where s_id in (2, 3)
group by v_id
having not bool_or(s_id = 3)
```

or equivalently:

```
having bool_and(s_id = 3)
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6H4ubXubMgJuoadXuxHbv4/0) is a db fiddle.

Comment: :-) That would break my brain if I ever meet this code in any project :-) SO need another  rating system to "like" but not "upvote" :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the solution you're looking for will always be comparing 2 and 3, or 3 and 4, or 5 and 6 (or the first number and the number above it) then you will likely use a left join to itself on b.s_id - 1 for the second table, and only where the second one is null on that value for b.s_id.

The part you're looking for here (if you want to avoid a subquery) is joining as well on v_id then filtering to WHERE b.v_id IS NULL.

If you only care about a.s_id = 2, specify that in the WHERE clause. Use the JOIN to get the data married together correctly.

```
`SELECT a.* 
  from table1 a 
  LEFT 
  JOIN table1 b 
    ON a.s_id = b.s_id -1
   AND a.v_id = b.v_id
 WHERE b.v_id IS NULL
   AND a.s_id = 2`
```